# CodeCharge : is it any good?

Tags: codecharge

A job came in to me that's built with [CodeCharge](http://www.yessoftware.com/) - had a look at it and seems to be a pretty basic point-and-click site builder tool. Has anyone got any in-depth experience with it? My first reaction is one of horror and to just rebuild the code in Rails or PHP but I thought I'd ask the question first, maybe i'm missing something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently evaluating it for use in quickly producing a back-office environment, and it seems a very comfortable way of getting an interface up and running quickly.
Once the code is generated it is simple, but easily modified for any special needs you have.

In short it is a very good tool (though it would seem that [Iron Speed Designer](http://www.ironspeed.com/) is much better though much more expensive) for what it does - fast prototyping and almost no coding approach to developing a web application. In my opinion, not much different than a Ruby On Rails application in terms of functionality, and, I can generate the code in any language I want.

You have to realize, it is all about speed - some quality is thrown in, but it is a very generic of quality - this is NOT a custom application, mind you, the resulting code you get here might not be pretty but it is a few level higher than your average script kiddie code.

I'm seriously considering this tool for creating back-office applications for sites I develop - a fast and easy solution instead of mucking around in tables of data and useless and repetitive SQL code.

Comment: +1 - This tool definitely works well as a back-office/intra-office website creator.  The sites turn out clean-looking and are consistent for the end users.

Comment: Agreed that CCS makes the common stuff really quick and simple (tables of results, CRUD forms, security on items, styles). I find it leaves me time to work on the hard problems instead - and the less code I type, the less likely it is to be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Codecharge is a powerful tool that I have used for over 10 years to build very large content management systems, CRMs and many other management type tools.

Its far from simple once you get into it, and honestly when you use a tool like Codecharge to cleanly generate your user interfaces, you end up with a healthier application that can last many many years.

For instance, I have three clients that have been running Codecharge created portals for over 10 years and they always comment how bug free they have been.

There is a learning curve to learning CodeCharge but it will also teach you what entire applications should have in place and it will please the executives every time because they can get functionality within hours or days rather than weeks or never.

Development teams will often not like it though, because they would rather hand code everything or use the latest and greatest approach to development.